# About grep usage and infix operator

Tags: linux, unix, grep

What is this expression supposed to be doing?

```
grep -i Keyword1 | grep -i Keyword2 file.txt
```

Is it supposed to return the lines which contain either keyword 1 or keyword 2? I ask this because that is not what i am getting.I am somehow always getting the lines with keyword 2 and also the thing doesnt seem to complete.I mean when you run a normal command it returns to the command prompt after finishing.Doesnt seem to be happening when I run the above.Is there some kind of piping happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't really make sense. `|` is a pipe, it redirects stdin/stdout: `a | b` redirects `a`s stdout to `b`s stdin. `grep`, without a file as parameter, will take input from stdin, which is why your command doesn't return.

What you want is

```
grep -i Keyword1 file.txt | grep -i Keyword2
```

Which will grep for `Keyword1`, and the output will be grepped for `Keyword2`. This will result in a logical `and`, filters for `Keyword1 AND Keyword2`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want logical or, you can use `grep -Ei '(Keyword1|Keyword2)' file.txt`

What you currently have is odd and wrong.  This is what you're intending to do:

```
grep -i Keyword1 file.txt | grep -i Keyword2
```

This will give you logical and.

Comment: that's a pipe, not a logical operator in this case.

Comment: Yes, you're correct.  I'm just using logical and and logical or as a descriptor.